# I have fetched the contact using cncontacts and able to display them on console screen, but not on table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontact

How to display contact in table view?

I have fetched the contacts via CNContactStore iOS 9.

```
- (void) getContacts {
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES) {
            //keys with fetching properties
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactImageDataKey];
            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContactsarray = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];   
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
                        }
            else {
                    for (CNContact *contact in cnContactsarray) {
                    //store all the contacts as per your requirement
                    NSLog(@"Name       :     %@",contact.givenName);
                    NSLog(@"Id         :     %@",contact.identifier);//the contact id which you want
                        [_ContactsCN addObject:contact];
                                  }


            }
            NSLog(@"array %@",_ContactsCN);
        }
    }];
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have to reload tableview after getting contacts

Comment: yes i did tried it...but still not able to display contact names on table view

Comment: reload table in main thread ... `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [tblview reloadData];
    });`

Comment: have you solved the issue, Amrut?

Comment: not yet...    cell.textLabel.text = [[_ContactsCN objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"givenName"];

Comment: this is my code for cellForRowAtIndexPath Method, where CNContact is my array and givenName is the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload data on main thread when your fetch contact from CNContact is complete

to run on main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{// reload your table here 
});
```

Comment: thanks again for your help sir...it did worked for me.